# Reading unkown file type with strange entries into R

Tags: r

I am completely new at this and here, so please have mercy.

I want to open an ASCII data file in R.

After several different attempts, I have tried `df=read.csv("C:MyDirectory" ,header=FALSE, sep="")`. 
This has produced a table with several variables, but some rows clearly contain the wrong information, some cells are blank, some contain NA values.

Any ideas what has gone wrong? I have gotten the file from an offical Spanish research institute:

http://www.cis.es/cis/opencm/ES/2_bancodatos/estudios/listaTematico.jsp?tema=1&todos=si

Then BARÓMETRO DE OCTUBRE 2017, to the right is a small link entitled "fichero de datos", which allows you to download after providing them with some info. The file giving the trouble is DA3191. If anyone could go through the trouble of helping me with this, it would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Try `data.table::fread`, but if your table is not *regularly* delimited, you're going to have to take a different approach to reading it in, and it may or may not be worth the effort.

Comment: What do you want to end up with?

Comment: Adding on to arvi's comment - for those two rows of input that you show - they seem to have different numbers of columns. So what result would you hope for? What sort of data is it supposed to be?

Comment: If all the columns have the same number of characters, then a fixed-width format it possible. In the example you post, it could be: col1: 4 chars, col2 2 chars (both blank in these rows), col3 4 chars (5999 and 4999), col4 3 chars (999 and 3), col 6 3 chars (2 and 99), ... (or many other possibilities). Reading it in treating each char as it's own column, you could make some guesses based on missingness. Metainformation about what you expect there to be would be very valuable.

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by the question of what I want to end up with. I want to read the data into R. I want columns, some entries will be blank, and that is it.

Comment: We're asking *What is the exact output you want for your sample input?* For the two rows of input, what columns would you want? The first column seems clear, 2111 and 2311 in row 1 and 2. The second column could be 5999999 and 4999, or it could be 5999 and 4999 - what do you want? Then the third column do you want 99 and 3, or NA and 3? Or 999 and 3? We can help you with a programmatic way to get to a goal, but we need to know the specifics of your goal.

Comment: You need a methodology that decides which entries will be blank, or where your blank entries will be. You can read in data with `readLines` and then manipulate delimiters with regular expressions `gsub` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1**

This looks like a fixed width format, so you need `read.fwf` instead of `read.csv` and friends. I made a screen shot of an almost random place of that file: my hypothesis is that the `99`'s and `98`'s etc are missing data codes, so the first `99` marked in yellow would belong to the same column with 4, 2, 0, etc, and the immediately following `99` (not marked) is in the same column with 0, 5, 7, etc.

[image]

**Part 2**

And then look at the file `ES3191` -- this looks like SPSS code (pardon my French!) containing the rules about reading in the data file. You can probably figure out the width of each column and what's in there from that file:

```
DATA LIST FILE= 'DA3191'
/ESTU 1-4 CUES 5-9 CCAA 10-11 PROV 12-13 MUN 14-16 TAMUNI 17 CAPITAL 18 DISTR 19-20 SECCION 21-23
ENTREV 24-27 P0 28 P0A 29-31 P1 32 P2 33 P3 34 P4 35 P5 36 P6 37 P701 38-39 P702 40-41 P703 42-43
P801 44-45 P802 46-47 P803 48-49 P901 50-51 P902 52-53 P903 54-55 P904 56-57 P905 58-59 P906 60-61
P907 62-63 P1001 64 P1002 65 P1003 66 P1101 67 P1102 68 P1103 69 P1104 70 P1201 71 P1202 72
P1203 73 P1204 74 P1205 75 P1206 76 P1207 77 P1208 78 P1209 79 P13 80-81 P13A 82-83 P1401 84-85
P1402 86-87 P1403 88-89 P1404 90-91 P1405 92-93 P1406 94-95 P1407 96-97 P1408 98-99 P1409 100-101
P1410 102-103 P1411 104-105 P1412 106-107 P1413 108-109 P1414 110-111 P1415 112-113 P1416 114-115
```

I'm not an SPSS expert  but I would guess that what it is trying to tell us is that

- columns 1-4 contain the variable "ESTU"
- columns 5-9 contain the variable "CUES"
- etc

For `read.fwf` you have to calculate each variable's "width" i.e. 4 characters for ESTU (if my reading was right) 5 characters for CUES etc.

**Part 3**

Using the guesses above, I used the following code to read in your data, and it looks like it works:

```
# this is copy/pasted SPSS code from file "ES3191"
txt <- "ESTU 1-4 CUES 5-9 CCAA 10-11 PROV 12-13 MUN 14-16 TAMUNI 17 CAPITAL 18 DISTR 19-20 SECCION 21-23
ENTREV 24-27 P0 28 P0A 29-31 P1 32 P2 33 P3 34 P4 35 P5 36 P6 37 P701 38-39 P702 40-41 P703 42-43
P801 44-45 P802 46-47 P803 48-49 P901 50-51 P902 52-53 P903 54-55 P904 56-57 P905 58-59 P906 60-61
P907 62-63 P1001 64 P1002 65 P1003 66 P1101 67 P1102 68 P1103 69 P1104 70 P1201 71 P1202 72
P1203 73 P1204 74 P1205 75 P1206 76 P1207 77 P1208 78 P1209 79 P13 80-81 P13A 82-83 P1401 84-85
P1402 86-87 P1403 88-89 P1404 90-91 P1405 92-93 P1406 94-95 P1407 96-97 P1408 98-99 P1409 100-101
P1410 102-103 P1411 104-105 P1412 106-107 P1413 108-109 P1414 110-111 P1415 112-113 P1416 114-115
P1501 116-117 P1502 118-119 P1503 120-121 P1504 122-123 P1505 124-125 P1506 126-127 P1507 128-129
P1508 130-131 P1509 132-133 P1510 134-135 P1511 136-137 P1512 138-139 P1513 140-141 P1514 142-143
P1515 144-145 P1516 146-147 P16 148 P17 149 P1801 150-151 P1802 152-153 P1803 154-155 P1804 156-157
P1805 158-159 P1806 160-161 P1807 162-163 P1808 164-165 P1809 166-167 P1810 168-169 P1811 170-171
P1812 172-173 P1813 174-175 P19 176 P20 177 P21 178-179 P22 180-181 P23 182-183 P2401 184-185
P2402 186-187 P2403 188-189 P2404 190-191 P2405 192-193 P2406 194-195 P2407 196-197 P2408 198-199
P2409 200-201 P2410 202-203 P2411 204-205 P2412 206-207 P2413 208-209 P2414 210-211 P2415 212-213
P2416 214-215 P25 216 P26 217 P27 218 P27A 219-220 P28 221-222 P29 223 P30 224-225 P31 226 P31A 227-228
P32 229 P32A 230 P33 231 P34 232 P35 233 P35A 234 P36 235 P37 236 P37A 237 P37B 238 P38 239-241
P39 242 P39A 243 P40 244-246 P41 247-248 P42 249-250 P43 251 P43A 252 P43B 253 P44 254 P4501 255
P4502 256 P4503 257 P4504 258 P4601 259-261(A) P4602 262-264(A) P4603 265-267(A) P4604 268-270(A)
P4605 271-273(A) P4701 274-276(A) P4702 277-279(A) P4703 280-282(A) P4704 283-285(A) P4705 286-288(A)
P48 289 P49 290 P50 291 P51 292 I1 293-295 I2 296-298 I3 299-301 I4 302-304 I5 305-307 I6 308-310
I7 311-313 I8 314-316 I9 317-319 E101 320-321 E102 322-323 E103 324-325 E2 326 E3 327-329 E4 330
C1 331 C1A 332-333 C2 334 C2A 335 C2B 336-337 C3 338 C4 339-340 P21R 341-342 P22R 343-344 VOTOSIMG 345-346
P27AR 347-348 RECUERDO 349-350 ESTUDIOS 351 OCUMAR11 352-353 RAMA09 354 CONDICION11 355-356
ESTATUS 357 "

# making a 2-column  matrix (name = left column, position = right column)
m <- matrix(scan(text=txt, what=""), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
m <- as.data.frame(m, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(m) <- c("Var", "Pos")
pos <- sub("(A)", "", m$Pos, fixed = TRUE) # some entries contain '(A)' - no idea what it means so deleting it
pos <- strsplit(pos, "-")
starts <- as.numeric(sapply(pos, head, 1)) # get the first element from left
ends <- as.numeric(sapply(pos, tail, 1)) # get the first element from right
w <- ends - starts +1

MyData <- read.fwf("R/MD3191/DA3191", widths = w)
names(MyData) <- m$Var

head(MyData)

  # ESTU CUES CCAA PROV MUN TAMUNI CAPITAL DISTR SECCION ENTREV P0 P0A P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6
# 1 3191    1   16    1  59      5       1     0       0      0  1   0  3  2  2  5  1  2
# 2 3191    2   16    1  59      5       1     0       0      0  1   0  4  2  3  5  2  3
# 3 3191    3   16    1  59      5       1     0       0      0  1   0  4  2  2  4  2  2
```

Comment: Thank you for going through all that trouble! It's super awesome! Thank you so much! Where on earth can you learn this kind of stuff from?! : )

Comment: It's mostly detective work so you can learn it from  Sherlock and Miss Marple :-). And the fact that I had to figure out  a similar (SPSS text + instructions) data structure recently probably helped quite a bit.